# uitextview and sqlite3

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uibutton, uitextview, ibaction

i would like to know whether is it possible to save the edited text in UITextView to sqlite3 by using a button?if so is there anywhere i can find the easiest way to do it?been googling but in vain..

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Create a new method and hook it up to your button's `touchUpInside` event.

Inside the method, grab the text from the `UITextView`, and then save it to your database.

Are you using Core Data? Or are you directly querying a SQLite database?